# Pandas foreach row multiplication - Speedup

Tags: python, pandas

I have extrem slow code:

A DataFrame called `tmp` with a MultiIndex (date and id) with around 2.000.000 lines and 2 columns (V1,V2).

```
                      V1    V2
Date          ID
2000-01-01    1      0.3   0.1
2000-01-01    2      0.3   0.1
2000-01-02    1      0.1   0.1
       .....
```

and `ref` contains around 5.000 lines with 250 columns

```
       C1   C2 ...  C250
ID
1     0.2  0.3 ...  0.1
2     1.2  1.3 ...  0.0
```

The expected result should have the following form:

```
            C1   C2   ...  C250
Date
2000-01-01   xx  xx   ...  xx
```

I've tried it with:

```
    sum1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=idx1, columns=idx2)
    sum2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=idx1, columns=idx2)

    def gen(row):
        i1 = row.name[0] # date
        i2 = row.name[1] # id

        sum1.loc[i1] += ref.loc[i2] * row['V1']
        sum2.loc[i1] += ref.loc[i2] * row['V2']

    tmp.apply( gen , axis=1)
```

Is it possible to speed this up - I've tried it with Cython but killed the app after 3 hours ...

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), then remove level `id` of `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=3),
                    'id':[1,2,1],
                    'V1':[.3,.3,.1],
                    'V2':[.1,.1,.1]}).set_index(['date','id'])
print (tmp)
                V1   V2
date       id          
2000-01-01 1   0.3  0.1
2000-01-02 2   0.3  0.1
2000-01-03 1   0.1  0.1

ref = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[.2,1.2],'C2':[.3,1.3], 'C250':[.1,0.0]}, index=[1,2])
ref.index.name = 'id'
print (ref)
     C1   C2  C250
id                
1   0.2  0.3   0.1
2   1.2  1.3   0.0
```

---

```
sum1 = ref.mul(tmp['V1'], axis=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
sum2 = ref.mul(tmp['V2'], axis=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (sum1)
              C1    C2  C250
date                        
2000-01-01  0.06  0.09  0.03
2000-01-02  0.36  0.39  0.00
2000-01-03  0.02  0.03  0.01

print (sum2)
              C1    C2  C250
date                        
2000-01-01  0.02  0.03  0.01
2000-01-02  0.12  0.13  0.00
2000-01-03  0.02  0.03  0.01
```

and then if need [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) columns:

```
sum1 = ref.mul(tmp['V1'], axis=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).sum(axis=1).to_frame('SUM')
sum2 = ref.mul(tmp['V2'], axis=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).sum(axis=1).to_frame('SUM')
print (sum1)
             SUM
date            
2000-01-01  0.18
2000-01-02  0.75
2000-01-03  0.06

print (sum2)
             SUM
date            
2000-01-01  0.06
2000-01-02  0.25
2000-01-03  0.06
```

Comment: I receive : ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names. Do i need to call it inside the gen function ?

Comment: I think `apply` is very slow, problem is with test data or only with real? I add test data to answer.

Comment: Thank you, the index name was different